# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: List argument must consist only of tuples or dictionaries

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have been trying to dump data into a mysql database using sqlalchemy. While I try do so its gives the error `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: List argument must consist only of tuples or dictionaries` . The following code is being used for insertion.

```
def insert_data(db, table, rows):

    db.execute(f"INSERT INTO {table} VALUES (%s)", rows)
    db.commit()
```

The content in `rows` is as follows.

```
[(1, 'asdsewadada', 'lajsdljasld', 'lol@gmail.com', 51)]
```

So, what I am inserting is list of tuples and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  What version of SQLAlchemy are you using?

Comment: I am using the version 1.4.1 @snakecharmerb

Comment: Still can't reproduce it - which connector package are you using?

Comment: I am creating the connection like this @snakecharmerb.
```
 engine = create_engine(connection + "://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + host + ":" + str(port) +"/" + database + "")
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    return Session()
```

Comment: What is `connection`, exactly?

Comment: Just got the same issue... I think it may have to do with the connection somehow.

Comment: @AlexLuisArias where you able to fix it? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, I was passing the wrong data type. I don’t remember now but I think you have to pass a list of dictionaries if your sql contains named variables

Comment: @Josh see above. Let me know if that doesn’t solve it and I’ll look up my code to see how i fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @AlexLuisArias ! I tried passing a list of tuples and list of lists but, no dice. Didn’t try the dictionary route. I ended up downgrading my sqlalchemy and that solved it.

Comment: @josh, can you share your query?

Answer (score 4):

Since version 2 of SQLAlchemy you should use dictionary instead of tuples:

> ```
>     :param parameters: parameters which will be bound into the statement.
>      This may be either a dictionary of parameter names to values,
>      or a mutable sequence (e.g. a list) of dictionaries.  When a
>      list of dictionaries is passed, the underlying statement execution
>      will make use of the DBAPI ``cursor.executemany()`` method.
>      When a single dictionary is passed, the DBAPI ``cursor.execute()``
>      method will be used.
> ```

So this should fix your code:

```
def insert_data(db: sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine, query: str, parameters: dict):
    log_headline: str = "insert_data() ::"
    """
    :param db:
    :param query: INSERT INTO votes (time_cast, candidate) VALUES (:time_cast, :candidate)
    :param parameters: {"time_cast": time_cast, "candidate": team}
    :return:
    """

    # Insert
    stmt = sqlalchemy.text(query)
    try:
        # Using a with statement ensures that the connection is always released
        # back into the pool at the end of statement (even if an error occurs)
        with db.connect() as conn:
            conn.execute(stmt, parameters=parameters)
            conn.commit()
        print(f"{log_headline} OK inserted data ")
    except Exception as e:
        # If something goes wrong, handle the error in this section. This might
        # involve retrying or adjusting parameters depending on the situation.
        print(f"{log_headline} Error {e}")
```

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be an sql alchemy error. I just had the same issue. I reverted back to sql alchemy 1.4.46 and was successful in inserting values.

Answer (score 0):

Can you format your row data like below and give it a try :

```
[{"Value1","value2"},{"Value1","value2"}]
```

Comment: The curly brackets are used for dictionaries and for dictionaries we have to define data in a key-value format. I don't think we can do it like this.

Comment: Curly braces can indeed be used to create sets. Cf. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#set-displays

Answer (score 0):

According to the sqlalchemy 2.0 doc : [link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#sending-parameters)

```
from sqlalchemy import text

params = ({"id":1, "fname":'asdsewadada', "lname":'lajsdljasld', "mail":'lol@gmail.com', "age":51})

def insert_data(db, table, rows):
    db.execute(text(f"INSERT INTO {table} VALUES (:id, :fname, :lname, :mail, :age)"), params)
    db.commit()
```

Answer (score -2):

I got the same errors when using sqlalchemy to execute insert-statement.
Then I determined a new way to implement my requirement. I was surprised the new method is rapid to load data into MySQL.

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from logger import setup_logger
import pandas as pd
import yaml

logger = setup_logger("util.py")


def load_file_into_database(filename, table_name, column_mapping):
    Base = declarative_base()

    try:
        with open('db_config.yaml', 'r') as file:
            db_config = yaml.safe_load(file)

        url = f'mysql+mysqlconnector://{db_config["user"]}:{db_config["password"]}@{db_config["host"]}/{db_config["database"]}'
        engine = create_engine(url)
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

        if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            df = pd.read_csv(filename)
        elif filename.endswith('.xlsx') or filename.endswith('.xls'):
            df = pd.read_excel(filename)
        else:
            logger.warning('Unknown file type')
            return

        df.rename(columns=column_mapping, inplace=True)
        df.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')
        logger.info('Data successfully loaded into the database')

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f'An error occurred while loading the file into the database: {e}')
```